# PostgreSQL update table then insert on another table

Tags: postgresql, update, insert, rails

I have a `User` table and a `Log` table. I need to update a field on the `User` table and insert a new entry on the `Log` table recording the update. I have written the statement for the update:

```
  UPDATE users SET free_shipping_until = spu.created_at::date + interval '1 year'
  FROM shipping_priority_users AS spu
  WHERE spu.role_id = #{role.id} and users.id = spu.user_id and spu.created_at is not null;
```

For each update I need to also add (probably in a transaction) an insert statement on the `Log` table which has the following columns

```
user_id: string,
created_at: timestamp
data: jsonb
```

- The data column contains a jsonb value including the `free_shipping_until` value from the update.

```
data: {"free_shipping_until": [null, "2021-07-30"]}
```

- `user_id` should match the updated record's value
- The `created_at` column is the current time, I'm using RoR and could interpolate the value with the expected format.

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.3

Comment: Maybe you want a trigger to do it automatically for all updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to do this in a single statement:

```
with changed_user as (
  UPDATE users 
    SET free_shipping_until = spu.created_at::date + interval '1 year'
  FROM shipping_priority_users AS spu
  WHERE spu.role_id = #{role.id} 
    and users.id = spu.user_id 
    and spu.created_at is not null
  returning *
) 
insert into log (user_id, created_at, data)
select id, 
       current_timestamp, 
       jsonb_build_object('free_shipping_until', array[null, free_shipping_until::text])
from changed_user;
```

from changed_user